NFT Collections with Token22
Is it possible to create verified collections with token22 and not metaplex?
I could add a collection address in the token extensions metadata, but is there anything preventing someone else creating nfts and inputing the same collection address?

The TokenGroup extension, which is currently under audit, will do exactly that, by allowing you to create a group and add member mints to it.
Once the audit passes, the functionality will get deployed. In the meantime, you can build token-2022 locally yourself and use the extension.
More info at https://spl.solana.com/token-2022/extensions#group and https://spl.solana.com/token-2022/extensions#member

As far as I know Token22 does not currently have a concept of collections. Anza is planning to integrate it in a future version.
Metaplex Token Metadata (which can be used with Token22) and Metaplex Core have it though.
